# POSTMAN to check if string exists then fail test

Tags: json, api, post, get, postman

I am running a POST request using POSTMAN. I am getting a 200 OK status however there is an error in the response body and nothing is being inserted in the database. I'm trying to do an If statement that checks the following string:

```
"Message": "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."
```

If the string exists then it should fail the request. If it doesn't exist then I will know it has worked.

This is what I have tried to do:

```
  pm.test("Successful POST request", function () {

    pm.expect(pm.response.code).to.be.oneOf([201,202]);
}); 

pm.test("Status code name has string", function () {
    pm.response.to.have.status("Object reference not set to an instance of an object.");
});
```

The outcome is a 200 OK even though the POST didn't work. I have pasted half of the response.

```
 "TransStatus": 1,

    "Exception": {

        "ClassName": "NRules.RuleActionEvaluationException",

        "Message": "Failed to evaluate rule action",

        "Data": null,

        "InnerException": {

            "ClassName": "System.NullReferenceException",

            "Message": "Object reference not set to an instance of an object.",
```

Comment: First of all, the issue is with your api which returns 200 status code even when error occurred. I believe it is not built as per best practices. If you can change the api code, your issues will be resolved.

Comment: Rather than changing the API code is there an actual way of doing it?

Comment: Yes, there is a way, but I believe that if you throw a radio to ground and it starts working, that is not a *right* solution. You need to fix it with a technician.